# slide show used from w3 schools

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question regarding a slide show I am building for an assignment. My debugging skills are not the best as I am new to HTML and JS. My problem comes from getting a typeError from a line in my slideshow JS. The problem is in this block here:

```
 var slideIndex = 1;
 showSlides(slideIndex);

 function plusSlides(n) {
   showSlides(slideIndex += n);
 }

 function currentSlide(n) {
   showSlides(slideIndex = n);
 }

 function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of 
undefined at showSlides
```

referring to this line:

```
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
```

Comment: which line, please post the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Whenever asking about an error message, always quote the error message verbatim in the question (using copy and paste, not retyping it). Since the error message will refer to a line number, tell us which line in your code it's referring to.

Comment: error is getting in " slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; "

(index):284 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at showSlides

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add information to it, not comments.

Comment: Since you've said you're new to this stuff, can I **strongly** encourage you not to use that bracing style. It's hard to read and hard to maintain. I urge you to use one of the standard styles. By far the most popular is the obnoxiously-named ["one true brace style"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Variant:_1TBS_(OTBS)).

Comment: this is the line where error is referring -> slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

Comment: Please stop learning from w3schools. Index should start at 0, not at 1. Also, the slides should be cached on init, not query the DOM in search for class elements on every slideshow click. That's not stuff w3schools can teach you. The [topic might be old](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)... but still very relevant.

Comment: now i added this slideIndex = 0;

Comment: @ShrenikSheth if you use `0` than you'll need a different resetting index logic. `if (slideIndex < 0) slideIndex  = slides.length - 1; if (slideIndex > slides.length - 1) slideIndex = 0;` But that's fine, and you can now finally use it properly like `slides[slideIndex]`

Comment: yes i got it by adding if (!slides.length) {return; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that the error refers to assumes that there will be at least one slide in `slides`, but there can be no slides at all, and apparently there are no slides when you call your function.

You can bail out of the function early if there are no slides:

```
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (!slides.length) { // ***
    return;             // ***
  }                     // ***
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

As for *why* there aren't any slides, my guess would be that you're running this code too soon. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)'s answers for reasons you may not be seeing any matching elements.

Comment: If this answer is what you were looking for, then you should accept the answer, @ShrenikSheth.